# Diffusion capacitence

Tags: cmos, capacitance, delay

I am trying to figure out the capacitance seen at each node, given that the source and drain diffusion capacitance is shared in the nmos stack. Given that the fingered layout uses a finger width of W=2 I want to try to find the capacitance at both B and N. I thought that based on the widths in the nmos stack the shared diffusion would be equal to (6+2)/2 unit C but I seems like I am wrong. I also thought that both N and B nodes would experience the same capacitance but I'm not sure. Can anyone explain why my analysis is incorrect?

[image: CMOS gate in question]

Answer (score -1):

Node N has 6 + 6 of Nchannel

Node B has 6 + 6 of Pchannel, 6 of Nchannel, 12 of Pch gate and 2W (12?) of Nch gate.

No way are B and N of the same capacitance.

Comment: I believe that would be the case for a layout with unshared diffusion regions but in the case of a layout (with finger width W=2) would't the capacitance of both p and n network should be drastically reduced?

Comment: Depends on whether the diffusions are shared. But that was not part of your questions.